# Transforming a vector in a loop without modifying the original vector

Tags: list-manipulation

How can we apply a duty on elements of vectors but they remain unchanged for the next processes:

For instance we have a process governed by these lines. However, in one loop process some elements of `Ai's` replace by zero (if they equal to 1) but in the start of the next loop, we must have the same `Ai` as the first of the previous loop (original `Ai`).

```
Subscript[A, 1] = {{0}, {0}}; Subscript[A, 2] = {{0}, {1}};
Subscript[A, 3] = {{1}, {0}}; Subscript[A, 4] = {{1}, {1}};

Do[
 Do[
   Do[
    If[
           Subscript[A, i][[j]] = Subscript[A, i][[j + 1]] == 1,,
               Subscript[A, i][[j]] = Subscript[A, i][[j + 1]] = 0; 
               matrix[[k, i]] += delta[Subscript[A, k], Subscript[A, i]]; 

     ],
      {j, 1, nn - 1}]
   , {i, 1, 2^nn}
   ]
, {l, 1, 2^nn}]
```

Prevent to being more ambiguous, matrix is not important to be shown.

Comment: If the answer below answered your questions, please accept it by clicking the grey arrow!

Comment: @march, By the way, your comment about change all variables with subscripts to variables such as v[i] with no subscripts, has so helped me. Thanks a bunch for those comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're code does not run but I think I understand what you are trying to do.  You can make use of `Module` to make copies of the $A_i$ for use in the calculation.

```
If[Subscript[A, i][[j]] = Subscript[A, i][[j + 1]] == 1,
 ,
 Module[{a = Subscript[A, i]}, 
  a[[j]] = a[[j + 1]] = 0;
  matrix[[k, i]] += delta[Subscript[A, k], a];]
 ]
```

`a` is manipulated leaving $A_i$ untouched.